# Динамическое подключение reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть приложение на React-Redux.

Конфиг store:

```
function config(initialState) {
    const logger = createLogger();
    const store = createStore(
        reducer, 
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextReducer = require('../reducers')
            store.replaceReducer(nextReducer)
        })
    }

    return store;
}
```

reducer - это:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import user from './user';
...
import dashboard from '../../dashboard/reducers';

export default combineReducers({
    api: api,
    ...
    dashboard: dashboard
});
```

reducer'ов в итоге очень много. Можно ли как нибудь поддерживать только нужное их количество в приложении? Динамически переопределять и тд.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Только в размере объекта-аргумента для combineReducers?
Есть конечно вариант вместо _export default_ делать экспорт заранее определенных наборов редьюсеров и в функции config создавать стор из этих наборов, но проблема в том, что эта функция инициализируется раньше чем приложение, поэтому туда не получится вынести какую-либо бизнес-логику. 
Для решения Вашего вопроса можно лишь порекомендовать пересмотреть/оптимизировать состав редьюсеров

Comment: Может быть динамика облегчит нагрузку на браузер, если редьюсеров действительно много. Еще думал над тем, чтобы в определенный момент отключить прослушку редьюсерами определенных действий. К примеру, на закрытие диалога добавления идет обновление списка, а на закрытие диалога изменения чтобы шло обновление одного элемента. Понятно, что это можно сделать другими средствами, просто рассматриваю этот вариант.

Comment: Боюсь что подобный вариант, даже если он и реализуем, не принесет должной пользы. Это все равно что снимать колеса с машины после каждой поездки - перетасовка состава редьюсеров и пересбор стора довольно затратная операция. В качестве _best practices_ рекомендуют активно использовать _shouldComponentUpdate_ и в нем определять логику необходимости ре-рендера. Очень помогает отстрелить ненужные перерисовки и ускорить работу